# Mysql Indexing and Joins

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
SELECT `a`.restid, `b`.`name` AS execname, `c`.`dept_name`
FROM `tk_ticket` AS a
INNER JOIN `tk_acp_users` AS b ON `a`.`exec_id` = `b`.`id`
INNER JOIN `tk_ticket_dept` AS c ON `a`.`dept_id` = `c`.`dept_id`
WHERE `a`.`dept_id` IN(9,11)
AND `a`.`status` =  0
ORDER BY `a`.`date` DESC, `a`.`dept_id`
```

Explain output

```
1   SIMPLE  a   ALL exec_id_2   5391    Using  where; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  b   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 2 tk_new_db.a.exec_id   1   
1   SIMPLE  c   eq_ref  PRIMARY PRIMARY 1 tk_new_db.a.dept_id   1   Using where
```

When i run an explain I get a full table scan for table a, how do i prevent this from happening i added a key (exec_id,dept_id,status) but this index is not considered.

Comment: What about primary keys?

Comment: Can you post the output of explain plan?

Comment: I guess "ORDER BY `a`.`date`" causes the full table scan. No time to test it, so that's just a blind guess, sorry.

Comment: @timur even after i remove the order by clause i get a full table scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think MySQL can use the index on (exec_id,dept_id,status) here, because there's no exec_id in your WHERE clause. Try adding an index on (dept_id,status) instead and perhaps put a separate one on (exec_id) for the JOIN. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/multiple-column-indexes.html

Answer (score 0):

Since your WHERE clause uses dept_id and status , but not exec_id , the index that you've created won't be used.

This is as , if the table has a multiple-column index, any leftmost prefix of the index can be used by the optimizer to find rows. For example, if you have a three-column index on (col1, col2, col3), you have indexed search capabilities on (col1), (col1, col2), and (col1, col2, col3).

MySQL cannot use an index if the columns do not form a leftmost prefix of the index

You could read up more , here : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html